# Есть ли в Delphi сборщик мусора?

Tags: delphi, сборщик-мусора

Предположим, есть некая функция, которая выполняется каждые 0.5 секунд:

```
procedure func();
var
  list: TStringList;
  str: string;
begin
  list := TStringList.Create();
  str := 'STRING';
  ...
end;
```

Вопрос такой: будут ли автоматически удалены из памяти локальные переменные при отработке функции? И вообще присутствует в ли в Delphi механизм, схожий с Garbage Collector( Java, C# ) ?

Answer (score 4):

Память, выделенная под переменные встроенных типов данных (например `integer`, `real`, `string`, статические массивы и т.д.) будет освобождена автоматически. А для экземпляров классов не будет, тут надо самому уничтожать экземпляры через `Destroy` или `FreeAndNil(obj)`.

Delphi генерирует нативный код. А C# и Java байт-код, который исполяется виртуальной машиной и она же следит за использованием памяти. В принципе в Delphi можно реализовать подобное для экземпляров классов, но тогда все классы должны быть наследованы от `TInterfacedObject`. В этом случае если на экземпляр класса никто не ссылается, то он автоматически уничтожается.

Comment: В вашем случае память, выделенная под переменную str, будет освобождена. Память, выделенная под переменную-ссылку list, тоже будет освобождена (это 4 или 8 байт в зависимости от платформы, под которую компилируете), а вот область памяти, на которую она ссылается не будет освобождена.

Comment: Java и C# не выполняются на виртуальной машине, что вы! Ваша информация устарела лет на 5. Сейчас JIT компилирует в нативный код.

Comment: Наличие GC никак не противоречит компилированию в нативный код, например D.

Answer (score 0):

В Delphi для мобильных платформ (только для DCCIOS32, DCCIOS32ARM, and DCCAARM - это iOS и Android) теперь есть [ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers). Это не сборщик мусора, но работает похоже. По сути это то же самое, что было с интерфейсами, но теперь это "родное" свойство для других классов/объектов. В вашем примере с использованием ARC все будет хорошо.

Comment: А также: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456116/delphi-arc-compilers-memory-management

Answer (score -3):

Да будут удалены.
То есть вполне можете использовать одинаковые локальные переменные в разных функциях.

Comment: В данном случае речь идет не об использовании одноименных переменных в разных функциях :) Интересует, что происходит после выполнения функции, а не на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Собственно я имел ввиду то что написано выше. Но вот выразился вот так :)